# MTN MOMO API CreateAPI User - 401 Access Denied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

I need you help with the MTN MOMO API...I am posting below some code I tried debugging for the entire day yesterday. The code works in Postman but the same fails to work in browser since Browsers implement `CORS( Access-Control-Allow-Origin)`. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I was able to work around the CORS issue, now am stuck on the **`error ' POST https://sandbox.momodeveloper.mtn.com/v1_0/apiuser 401 (Access Denied)  '`**. This error worries me since I have give all parameters as needed by the API call.

```
async function postData() {
    try {
      let result = await fetch(
        "https://sandbox.momodeveloper.mtn.com/v1_0/apiuser",
        {
          method: "post",
          mode: "no-cors",
          headers: {
            "X-Reference-Id": "9de3e973-53c8-4cc4-a8eb-25a4a9ccb5f9",
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "15e4e92ef6914728b8414e2bb67d7357",
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            providerCallbackHost: "username",
          }),
        }
      );
      console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

I decided to post the KEYS since they are on sandbox and not live account(I have no live account yet).
THe full API is here...https://momodeveloper.mtn.com/

Comment: If the API doesn't already set the right CORS headers, that's generally a sign you shouldn't be accessing it from the client side. Also you should rotate your keys even if they're only for the sandbox.

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I am facing the same problem ...